# Targeting the first div that doesn't contain certain things

Tags: html, css

I have a page that contains several divs with the classname `row`.

```
<section>
    <div class="row"> [...] </div>
    <div class="row"> [...] </div>
    <div class="row"> [...] </div>
</section>
```

I want to target the first of these so that I can apply certain spacing to them.

```
section div:nth-of-type(1) {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

However, in some cases, the div I want to affect is not actually the first div in the section. It's the first div after a div that contains a `noscript` tag.

How can I ensure I am targeting the correct div in this case? And are there better approaches?

Comment: *after a div that contains a noscript tag* - It is better you add some class to that `div` which contains the noscript tag. Without that this would be tough (impossible I think) with pure CSS because you can select a sibling or descendant with CSS but not sibling of the parent or parent.

Comment: I dont think this can be done with pure CSS... Jquery will save you..

Comment: It's not possible in CSS because there is no parent selector. So you can't dive into a div element to see whether it contains a noscript tag and then go back and select the next sibling element.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS you cannot select an element based on its children (exsistent or not).

With jQuery, you can try something like:

```
$('div.row:not(:has(noscript))').css('margin-top', '10px');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `nth-of-type` or `first-of-type` here type means `<div>` of `<p>` etc. It will not work if you use class selector because the type remains same.

**For Example**

```
<p>hello</p>
<div class="row">hello</div>
```

In above code if you use `div:nth-of-type(1)` then it will catch `<div class="row">hello</div>` because its first div.

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/czv0z93t/

**But**

```
<div class="first">Hello</div>
<div class="row">Hello</div>
```

In above code if you use `.row:nth-of-type(1)` it will not work because its previous element type is also div.

So here you can simply use `.row:nth-child(2)`.

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/czv0z93t/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would just have a much easier life and assign a class to all the ones which you want to have special styling like `<div class='row no-top-border'>`

Though you can definitely experiment with `div.row > div[noscript], div.row:first-child {}`